# I have trouble writing code for prints the value of the combination n from k in the output and I keep getting errors because I am just learning Python

Tags: python

#I have trouble writing code for this question and I keep getting errors and I do not know what
the problem is because I am just learning Python.

## A function to calculate the combination of two numbers

```
def comb(n, k):
    sum1 = 1 
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        sum1 = sum1 * i
        if sum1 == 0:
            sum1 = 1
    sum2 = 1
    for j in range(1, k + 1):
        sum2 = sum2 * j
        if sum2 == 0:
            return 1
    sum3 = 1
    c = k - n
    for m in range(1, c + 1):
        sum3 = sum3 * m
        if sum3 == 0:
            return 1
    while k >= n:
        return sum1 / sum2 * sum3
```

###I have trouble writing code for this question and I keep getting errors and I do not know what
the problem is because I am just learning Python.##

Comment: What are you trying you do with this function? Please explain it clearly.

Comment: Can please edit the question and add the error message. It narrows the problems and helps us solving your problem.

Comment: When I call the function with `comb(0, 0)` I get no error. Show us how you call the function and give us the full error message.

Comment: This looks a bit like [comb from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb), why not use that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combinations formula is [image]

I have decided to put `n!` as a function, so your code would look less messy with loops:

```
def factorial(n):
    
# Returns factorial of a given number
# i.e. 3! = 6 etc.
# 

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        value = 1
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            value = value * i
        return value
```

The function `factorial` returns the factorial of a given number, then the second function `combinations` returns the number of given combinations between 2 int values:

```
def combinations(n, k):
    value = factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k))
    return value
```